# Event tracking + new window

Tags: google-analytics

I spent half a day on this and i still cant figure out how to track outbound links i open i a new window!

- i can track the event
- i can open the link in a new window

Problem: i'm opening 2 new windows

my code:

```
 <script>
  var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
  ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
  'transport': 'beacon',
  'hitCallback': function(){window.open(url, '_blank');}
  });
  }
 </script>

 <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com');">Check out example.com</a>
```

Comment: When you say open in a new window, you mean with a right click, followed by selecting 'open in new window' from the menu?

Comment: onclick. not right click. @JBrazier

Comment: I know you're using an onclick. I'm asking what your mechanism is for opening a new window, not for tracking.

Comment: no , i'm not using right click-open in new window at all.

Comment: Sorry, so is the issue here that you're opening a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do this via GTM? 
There are a type of script called Listener, they are very usefull to track things like his, i recomend you take a look.
With this , it's quiet easy to track the outbound clicks (via  tag )
I  leave you a post of Simo explaining this.

http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-outbound-links-in-gtm-v2/#gref

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question, but still might help someone with my solution.

```
function trackOutboundLink(url) {
    var params = {};
    params.hitCallback = function () {
        window.open(url);
    }
    ga("send", "event", "outbound", "click", url, params);
    return false;
}
```

It works on mobile and no 2 new windows on desktop.

Usage:

```
<a href="http://www.example.url" target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.url');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't need to provide `transport` and `hitCallback` if a link opens in a new window.

The universal solution that works for both normal links and new window links:

```html
<a href="http://www.example.url" target="_blank" onclick="trackOutboundLink(this)">
```

and:

```js
function trackOutboundLink (el) {
    let params
    if (!el.target) {
        event.preventDefault()
        params = {
            transport: 'beacon',
            hitCallback: function () {
                document.location = el.href
            },
        }
    }
    ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', el.href, params)
}
```